How to setup a JMeter test for an OAuth2 OpenID Connect website
We need to perform load testing against a website that authenticates using OpenID Connect with an external identity provider.  We're having trouble understanding how to parameterize all of the dynamic values (state, nonce, etc) that's involved in the process.
We're also having trouble finding a "tutorial" or an example of how to do this with the tool.
Is there an existing tutorial on how to set this up?  Or is there a website dedicated to JMeter usage scenarios?
We've recorded a login process using the Network tab in the Chrome inspector and then converted that to a jmx file but we need to parameterize all of the dynamic headers and cookies.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you're looking for an example application you can check out i.e. Okta OpenID Connect Fun!
The guide for implementing correlation of the dynamic parameters: OpenID Connect - How to Load Test with JMeter
The general piece of advice: record your authentication flow 2 times and compare resulting .jmx scripts, all the values which will differ are a subject to correlation so you will need to either extract them from the previous responses using suitable JMeter Post-Processors or generate them using i.e. JMeter Functions
